# Concatenation of occurrences / XML and XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, key, concatenation

I have this kind of **XML** with similar beginning of url for `<platform>` and `<source>`:

```
<informations>
    <platform>http://networkcultures.org/</plateforme>
    <source>http://networkcultures.org/wpmu/theoryondemand/2011/07/11/distant-reading/</source>
</informations>
```

I would like to know with **XSL** how to have this output in **HTML**, in order to combine/concatenate the two markups in the beginning and have after **the rest** of `<source>` :

```
<span class="url">
    <span class="platform"><xsl:value-of select="platform"/></span>
    <xsl:value-of select="the rest of <source>"/>
</span>
```

I've searched for `<xsl:key>` or `generate-id()` but without success. Hope you'll understand my question. And thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the second `<xsl:value-of>` as follows:

```
<span class="url">
    <span class="platform"><xsl:value-of select="platform"/></span>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(source, platform)" />
</span>
```

This assumes that the string value of `<platform>` will *always* occur at the beginning of `<source>`. Otherwise, `substring-after()` returns an empty string.

This will give, e.g.

```
<span class="url">
    <span class="platform">http://networkcultures.org/</span>wpmu/theoryondemand/2011/07/11/distant-reading/
</span>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but my goal is to give to differents styles (CSS) of the spans therefore to treat independently the two part of the `source` markup. You see?

Comment: @Yann, I don't understand the difference between what I suggested and what you're trying to accomplish. Do you want to output three `<span>` elements? Please edit your question to show the desired output. I've edited my answer to make sure what I'm suggesting is clear.

Comment: Excuse-me, I'm not really good for XSL. But now, it's clear. Thanks again for your help!